# SDL2 window leave/enter events fire in relative mouse mode

Tags: c++, mouseevent, sdl-2

I'm using SDL 2.0.5 in my application (Win10 x64 vc12), where I implemented the following behaviors:

- Approaching left edge of window with cursor: sets mouse mode to relative
- Right click: toggles mouse relative mode and place mouse to center
- Window leave/enter events are tracked (want to build further actions on them)

The full code is

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_syswm.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

SDL_Window *sdl_window = NULL;

int EventFilter(void *userdata, SDL_Event *event) {
  switch (event->type) {
    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT: {
      SDL_WindowEvent e = event->window;
      switch (e.event) {
        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ENTER:
          std::cout << "window enter\n";
          break;
        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_LEAVE:
          std::cout << "window leave\n";
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      break;
    }
    case SDL_MOUSEMOTION: {
      SDL_MouseMotionEvent e = event->motion;
      std::cout << e.x << ", " << e.y << std::endl;
      if (e.x < 20) {
        std::cout << "relative mode ON\n";
        SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE);
        SDL_PumpEvents();
        SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_WINDOWEVENT_LEAVE);
      }
      break;
    }
    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: {
      SDL_MouseButtonEvent e = event->button;
      if (e.button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT) {
        SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_GetRelativeMouseMode() ? SDL_FALSE
                                                            : SDL_TRUE);
        if (!SDL_GetRelativeMouseMode())
          SDL_WarpMouseInWindow(sdl_window, 800 / 2, 600 / 2);
      }
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  SDL_AddEventWatch(EventFilter, NULL);
  sdl_window = SDL_CreateWindow(
      "test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED_DISPLAY(1),
      SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED_DISPLAY(1), 800, 600,
      SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_INPUT_FOCUS);

  while (1) {
    SDL_PumpEvents();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

With the current setup, if I move the cursor to the left edge of the window **quickly** it runs out of window and reports the following events:

```
relative mode ON
window leave
```

How is it possible? It seems to be an invalid state to me. After setting relative mouse mode it shouldn't leave the window like that. I can only continue using my app by unfocusing/focusing my window, which is obviously not ideal.

How can I fix or work around this situation? Any suggestion is appreciated!

---

As you can see I tried to manually flush window leave event after setting relative mode but nothing changed.

I also tried to use `SDL_PollEvent` in my loop, which resulted in invalid state as well but in a different way: It reported

```
relative mode ON
window leave
window enter
```

after which I haven't receive any window leave/enter events *at all*.